# Search Excel file for a string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm basically looking to write a script that checks if a certain string exists on a specific file on the network, and return 0 or 1.

So basically:

```
If "C:\myfile.xls" exists THEN
  If "C:\myfile.xls" contains string "no data found" THEN
    Return 0
  ELSE
    Return 1
ELSE
  Return 0
END
```

Is this possible?  Much appreciated in advance!!

I believe I am running v2.0

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5466
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't ask yes/no questions unless you expect the answer to be either "yes" or "no". In your case it's "yes", but you need Excel installed on the host:

```
function Check-File($filename) {
  $found = 0

  if ( Test-Path -LiteralPath $filename ) {
    $xl = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
    $wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($filename)
    if ( [bool]$xl.Cells.Find("no data found") ) { $found = 1 }
    $wb.Close()
    $xl.Quit()
  }

  $found
}

Check-File "C:\myfile.xls"
```

Comment: Missing opening curly bracket. Fixed.